# How to use "Cases" for isolating terms of a sum in a nice way?

Tags: pattern-matching, filtering, xact

I'd like to isolate some terms with specific patterns within a sum that I called `chunk`.

```
chunk=-4*A[β, b]*dg[-α, η]*dg[-η, -β]*epsilong[-γ, -δ, -ϵ, -ζ]*CD[δ][A[γ, -a]]*CD[ζ][A[ϵ, -b]] -4*pertvf[α, a]*pertvf[β, b]*epsilong[-β, -γ, -δ, -ϵ]*CD[γ][A[-α, -b]]*CD[ϵ][A[δ, -a]] +2*A[β, -a]*A[γ, b]*dg[ζ, -α]*epsilong[-δ, -ϵ, -ζ, -η]*CD[-γ][dg[η, -β]]*CD[ϵ][A[δ, -b]] -4*epsilong[-α, -γ, -δ, -ϵ]*pertvf[β, b]*CD[δ][A[γ, -b]]*CD[ϵ][pertvf[-β, -a]] +A[β, -a]*A[γ, b]*A[δ, -b]*epsilong[-δ, -ϵ, -ζ, -η]*CD[-γ][dg[ϵ, -α]]*CD[η][dg[ζ, -β]] -4*A[β, b]*epsilong[-α, -γ, -δ, -ϵ]*CD[-β][pertvf[γ, -a]]*CD[ϵ][pertvf[δ, -b]] +2*A[β, b]*dg[-δ, -α]*epsilong[-β, -γ, -ϵ, -ζ]*CD[δ][A[γ, -a]]*CD[ζ][A[ϵ, -b]] -2*epsilong[-α, -γ, -δ, -ϵ]*pertvf[β, b]*CD[γ][A[-β, -a]]*CD[ϵ][A[δ, -b]] +A[β, -a]*A[γ, b]*epsilong[-γ, -δ, -ϵ, -ζ]*CD[-α][A[δ, -b]]*CD[ζ][dg[ϵ, -β]] -2*A[β, b]*epsilong[-α, -γ, -δ, -ϵ]*CD[-β][A[γ, -a]]*CD[ϵ][pertvf[δ, -b]] +8*dg[ζ, -α]*epsilong[-γ, -δ, -ϵ, -ζ]*pertvf[β, b]*CD[γ][A[-β, -a]]*CD[ϵ][A[δ, -b]] +4*A[β, b]*dg[-ϵ, -α]*epsilong[-β, -γ, -δ, -ζ]*CD[δ][A[γ, -a]]*CD[ζ][pertvf[ϵ, -b]] -2*A[β, b]*epsilong[-γ, -δ, -ϵ, -ζ]*pertvf[γ, -a]*CD[-β][dg[ζ, -α]]*CD[ϵ][A[δ, -b]] -2*A[β, -a]*A[γ, b]*epsilong[-β, -δ, -ϵ, -ζ]*CD[-γ][dg[ζ, -α]]*CD[ϵ][pertvf[δ, -b]]
```

[image: This is how <code>chunk</code> looks for Mathematica]

The terms have to be isolated in 4 different groups according to the following requirements:

1)  They have exactly two `dg[__,__]`

2)  They have exactly two `pertvf[__,__]`

3)  They have exactly one `dg[__,__]` and one `pertvf[__,__]`

4)  They have exactly one `dg[__,__]` or one `pertvf[__,__]`

In each case, it doesn't matter if they're inside the `CD[__][__]` functions or not.

---

I think 'Cases' is the best function to do this but I'll have to ask you, guys, for more suggestions or examples to gain more intuition about this commands. Until now, I've just found the following two commands to get the job partially done:

```
(chunk // Cases[#, dg[__,__]___] & // Apply[Plus, #] &)
(chunk // Cases[#, pertvf[__,__]___] & // Apply[Plus, #] &)
```

[image: This is how both of this commands work when applied to <code>chunk</code>]

The first one isolates all kind of terms with at least one `dg[__,__]` outside `CD[__][__]`. (It needs improvement to take into account thee cases where `dg[__,__]` is inside but, also, distinguish those cases where there are more than one `dg[__,__]`). The second one does the same for `pertvf[__,__]`.

---

So far, I've been using: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Patterns.html

and this post:
 [how to extract some terms out from an expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16086/how-to-extract-some-terms-out-from-an-expression)

I'm not able to incorporate the 4 requirements yet. What do you suggest, how could I do that?

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not use `Cases` for this procedure.

```
chunk2 = List @@ chunk;
chunk3 = List @@@ chunk2 /. CD[_][x_] :> x;
chunk4 = Tally /@ Map[Head, chunk3, {2}];

group1 = Pick[chunk2, (MemberQ[#, {dg, 2}] &) /@ chunk4];
group2 = Pick[chunk2, (MemberQ[#, {pertvf, 2}] &) /@ chunk4];
group3 = Pick[chunk2, (MemberQ[#, {dg, 1}] && MemberQ[#, {pertvf, 1}] &) /@ chunk4];
group4 = Pick[chunk2, (MemberQ[#, {dg, 1}] || MemberQ[#, {pertvf, 1}] &) /@ chunk4];
```

Answer (score 2):

I would also not use `Cases`.
What about a bit old fashioned solution by marking the terms you are interested in explicitly, e.g., via

```
temp = chunk/.{dg[a__,b__]:>dgmarker * dg[a,b],pertvf[a__,b__]:>pertvfmarker * pervf[a,b]}
```

I assume that `CD` represents a covariant derivative, so you probably already know how to inform Mathematica that all `*marker`s are constants and should be dragged out outside `CD`.
Then you can simply get your `chunk`s 3 and 4 by

```
temp2 = Coefficient[temp, dgmarker,1];
chunk3 = Coefficient[temp2, partvfmarker,1]
chunk4 = Coefficient[temp2, partvfmarker,0]
```

Alternatively you could use `CoefficientList[temp,{dgmarker, pertvfmarker}]` (however, then you need to decipher which output is which `chunk`) or `CoefficientList[temp2,pertvfmarker]` (here the output is rather obvious) to get all the `chunk`s in one `List` at once.

Comment: I like the idea, I believe it is the most suitable one because of its simplicity - that'll help later when dealing with larger sums. Thanks!

Comment: Just let me add, for completeness, that (DefConstantSymbol) does the task you mentioned and informs Mathematica that all *markers are constants and should be dragged out outside CD.

Answer (score 2):

If you do want to use `Cases`. This does the trick (without polluting the global context).

```
Plus @@ Cases[
 chunk, 
 (dg[a__] | CD[_][ dg[a__]]) ( dg[b__] | CD[_][ dg[b__]]) _?(FreeQ[dg])
] (* case 1 *)
Plus @@ Cases[
 chunk, 
 (pertvf[a__] | CD[_][ pertvf[a__]]) (pertvf[b__] | CD[_][ pertvf[b__]]) _?(FreeQ[pertvf])
] (* case 2 *)
Plus @@ Cases[
 chunk,
 ( dg[a__] | CD[_][ dg[a__]]) (pertvf[b__] | CD[_][ pertvf[b__]])_?(FreeQ[pertvf | dg])
] (* case 3 *)
Plus @@ Cases[
 chunk,
 ( dg[a__] | CD[_][ dg[a__]] | pertvf[b__] | CD[_][ pertvf[b__]]) _?(FreeQ[pertvf | dg])
] (* case 4 *)
```